# Convert a swift function in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift

I am working on an Objective-C project and finding it hard to convert a swift 3 function to Objective-C. Can someone help me? Below is the code for swift 3 function

```
func checkIfStringOfArrayExists(_ arrayOfString: NSArray, inString string: NSString) -> Bool {
    for element in self.abusiveArray where self.txtChat.text.lowercased().contains(element as! String) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this function? Neither `arrayOfString` and `string` are used. Maybe you should write your own based on specific requirements...

Comment: Well I don't know much about objective-c, I tried to understand and write the code first, but when I was unable to write it. So I decided to ask for a little help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to find if given string contains at least one of the strings contained in the array to ban abusive words

```
- (BOOL) checkIfOfStringOfArray: (NSArray *) array inString: (NSString *) string {
    for (NSString * element in array) {
        if ([string containsString: element]) return YES;
    }
    return NO;        
}
```

Call like:

```
   BOOL hasAbusiveString = [self checkIfOfStringOfArray: self.abusiveArray inString:self.txtChat.text.lowercaseString];
```